# Alternative for ADmitmac to access dfs shares?

Tags: snow-leopard, windows, network

I can <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to hidden shares if I remember the names, but normal access of dfs shares would be nicer. I want to get rid of admitmac since it makes my system unstable and slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Samba](http://samba.org) version that powers all that functionality for Unix/Linux/OS X, supports Distributed FS “out of the box”; if I am not mistaken ADmitmac only provides a layer that handles configuration and automation of those tasks for you and adds a few services that might require a “server”. I have no experience with admitmac whatsoever so take this with a grain of salt.

With that said, OS X can join Active Directory networks created by either Samba servers or Windows 2003-2008. For more information check the [Apple Business](http://www.apple.com/business/solutions/it/directory.html) solutions, you might get away with what you need without having to use ADmitmac.

If your problem is that you have to type <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> every time you want to connect to a dfs share, you could always -once connected- drag that share to the right side of the dock, where it will create a direct access to the share. Next time you click on that, if the share is not connected, it will try to do that. This works for any type of connection (at least Windows Shares work too and I recall using nfs). That way you don’t have to type the name when you need the share.

Alternatively, you can “add” it to Favorites (I’m sure you’ve already seen this window):

[image: Connect to server]

Finally, here are a couple more resources you might want to check:

- [Apple’s free Seminar for Integrating OSX into Active Directory](http://www.seminars.apple.com/seminarsonline/activedir/apple/index.html?s=203&locs=us_en)
- [MCS + dslocal](http://managingosx.wordpress.com/2008/02/07/mcx-dslocal-and-leopard/)
- [Using Managed Preferences in the DSLocal domain](http://managingosx.wordpress.com/2008/02/07/mcx-dslocal-and-leopard/)